# How to get Google account to show offline scope using Azure App Service

Tags: android, ios, azure

I have an issue using the the information at the following blog post

https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/

I have an app that can login using windows or Google account.

With windows account all is well.

I am able to login and receive a refresh token.

This will then refresh with no issues.

With Google account I do not get the refresh token and google account does not ask my permission to have the offline scope.

Here is the code I use to login:

```
 return await client.LoginAsync(myView, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "access_type", "offline" } });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem could be. Are you able to collect a Fiddler trace?  Also, do you get prompted for consent if you visit https://<site-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google?access_type=offline in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think what the problem could be this (from Google's [OAuth documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline)):

> **Important**: When your application receives a refresh token, it is important to store that refresh token for future use. If your application loses the refresh token, it will have to re-prompt the user for consent before obtaining another refresh token. If you need to re-prompt the user for consent, include the prompt parameter in the authorization code request, and set the value to consent.

Basically, if you've already received a refresh token for a particular request, it sounds like Google won't give you new ones unless you *explicitly* prompt the user for consent for the offline scope.  You can do this by adding a **prompt=consent** query string parameter to your login. For example:

```
/.auth/login/google?access_type=offline&prompt=consent
```

I've seen this work for others. Give it a try and see if it resolves your issue too.